# Using variable as text() function output in matlab

Tags: matlab, text, input

I'm putting text into an image and saving it to my computer in Matlab. I am using the following code to do so:

```
ha = axes('Position',[.25 0 .5 .25],'Xlim',[0 1],'Ylim',[0 1],'Box','off','Visible','off','Units','normalized', 'clipping' , 'off');
text(0.5, .9,'This is my subtitle',...
'center','VerticalAlignment', 'bottom', 'FontSize', 18)
```

Currently, it is printing out the 'this is my subtitle' line. However, I want to use user input to determine what that text is. I have at the beginning of the code:

```
prompt = 'What is the subtitle of your image? ' ;
mysubtitle = input(prompt, 's');
```

How can I code the text() line to print the mysubtitle input as the subtitle on the image?

Note: when I say:

```
text(0.5, .9, mysubtitle....)
```

It gives an error message (for use of the text function) of 'Invalid parameter/value pair arguments'.

Comment: Can't you just replace 'this is my subtitle'  by mysubtitle in your call to text? Or maybe mysubtitle{1} i aleays forget if the output of prompt is a cell array

Comment: When I replace 'this is my subtitle' with mysubtitle, it gives the following error:
Invalid parameter/value pair arguments

When I replace it with mysubtitle{1}, it gives:
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
prompt = 'What is the subtitle of your image? ' ;
mysubtitle = input(prompt, 's');

ha = axes('Position',[.25 0 .5 .25],'Xlim',[0 1],'Ylim',[0 1],'Box','off','Visible','off','Units','normalized', 'clipping' , 'off');
text(0.5,.9,mysubtitle,'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'bottom', 'FontSize', 18)
```

Please make sure your example code is correct, makes it harder to answer. You had forgotten the 'HorizontalAlignment'!

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I didn't realize that I inadvertently deleted that... :D :D